# Controlling apps for a specific user

Tags: tablet, multi-user

I have no experience working with a tablet and am considering buying one for my son.

I would like to have control of apps installed on his user account. Maybe the access to Google Play or whatever app used for installing other apps would be password-protected. Or maybe the apps on his user account would only be installed by me after logging into the admin user account.

How can something like this be achieved? Are there any specific requirements that I need to be aware of when choosing a tablet for this to be achievable?

**UPDATE**: I ended up using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sp.protector.free&hl=en&gl=US).

Comment: Check out [Google Family Link](https://families.google.com/familylink/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Google Family Link](https://families.google.com/familylink/), as commented by Noah Broyles in the question comments would be a really nice option, that would cover most of your needs. Its target is exactly parents that would like to limit kids when using mobiles - you could control the time he uses it, block or allow app downloads, and so on. The app also suggest constructive apps (for learning) and has localization enabled, so parents would know where their kids are

I, however, have a complementary suggestion (that could be used together with Google Family Link) - the [dfndr security: antivírus](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.psafe.msuite). I use it on my phone not only for the antivirus stuff (which I can't really tell if it is good or not), but it contains an app blocker (vault) that I use for bank apps (and you could use for any app you have installed but don't want your kid to open). Once configured, every time you try to enter the selected apps, the screen will be blocked asking for a pattern/password - that would be different from the one you use to unlock the phone. I'm not sure this would be the only antivirus that has such feature, but you might look for similar apps - it is good, for instance, for blocking any app that may allow the kid to spend money in it.

Comment: I see that Google Family Link allows me to either approve or disapprove apps that my son wants to download from Google Play Store. But can I block him from entering the Google Play Store in the first place? Similarly, can I password-protect Google Play Store using the antivirus that you suggested?

Comment: Yes, you can block Google Play Store or any other app with that

Comment: "with that" means with either of them?

Comment: Do ads pop up at the time when the antivirus asks for a password?

Comment: There are adds in the app - but there is an option to pay to remove the adds, if I'm not mistaken (I'm not sure because I didn't look for it - those adds don't bother me).

Comment: Also, sorry for the ambiguous sentence. I meant you can block Google Play Store and any other app with the vault tool present on the antivirus app.

Comment: Can the ads include pictures of (immodestly dressed) women?

Comment: I've never seen one - I strongly believe it does not include that. However, adds usually comes from google, and they show based on what their AI recommends for the user based on your activity/profile - so I can't really tell what will appear for your kids.